# gmic installed but not showing in GIMP, Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: plugins, gimp

I installed gmic for Gimp from apt on 22.04

```
sudo apt install gmic
```

It's nowhere to be found in Gimp Filters or anywhere else that I can see.

Comment: Was gimp itself installed via apt - or as a snap or flatpak?

Comment: In Software it says source: Ubuntu (deb)

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you are wanting to use G'MIC as a GIMP plugin?

Installing `gmic` is just the binary for G'MIC, not the GIMP plugin.

To install and access the GIMP plugin, run:

`apt install gimp-gmic`

Then open GIMP, and go to *Filters* -> *G'MIC Qt*  (at the bottom of the menu.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the instructions from:
https://linuxhint.com/gmic-pre-image-processing-plugin-gimp/
It said it was posted one year ago. So I'm not sure it's for 22.04 or for 64-bit. But it worked. Hope I don't have problems later.
This is what I did:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:otto-kesselgulasch/gimp
sudo apt update
sudo apt install gimp-gmic
```